# Ambiguous column name when trying to outer join

Tags: c#, gridview, outer-join

I have a appointment form which will display data in a gridview based on the appointment table. I write the select statement so that patientID will be changed to pFirstName in patient table, and mcID will be changed to mcCentre in the medicalcentre table. There is a WHERE query because I only want to display appointment/row which belongs to only the current user has login. When i debug i got this error Ambiguous column name patientID.

***My view appointment form***

[image]

**My 3 tables of appointment, medicalcentre and patient.**

[image]

**My view appointment form code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class member_viewappointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // call BindGridView
            bindGridView();

        }
    }

    private void bindGridView()
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT aStatus, aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, med.mcCentre, pat.pFirstName from appointment AS app ";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE as med on app.appointmentid = med.mcid";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on app.patientid = pat.patientid ";
        strCommandText += " WHERE patientid = " + ID.ToString();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            myConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdViewAppointment.DataSource = dt;
            grdViewAppointment.DataBind();
            lblResult.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem :** you have `patientid` column in both the tables (`appointment` and `MEDICALCENTRE`).so when you use  column name `patientid` alone, without mentioning the table name that it belongs to , it can not identify and leads to an ambigious situation.

**Solution:** so you should mention the table name or table alias name before the columnname `patientid` to remove the ambiguity that to which table the `patientid` belongs to.

Replace This:

```
strCommandText += " WHERE patientid = " + ID.ToString();
```

With This:

```
strCommandText += " WHERE app.patientid = " + ID.ToString();
```

**Suggestion:** your `SELECT` query is open to `SQL Injection Attacks`, so i would suggest you to use the `Parameterised queries` to avoid them.

**Using Parameterised queries:**

```
strCommandText += " WHERE patientid = @patientid";
try
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid",ID.ToString());
/*remaining same*/
}
```